# Rails association not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables, Projects and Categories. I've pre-loaded Categories with 4 rows and each Project must belong to one of the 4. However, when I try to add the association between an existing project and an existing category in the command line, I get this:

```
> Project.find(11).category = Category.find(1)
Project Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
Category Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Category id: 1, name: "Photography", created_at: "2012-10-05 00:07:37", updated_at: "2012-10-05 00:07:37"> 
1.9.3p194 :004 > Project.find(11).category
Project Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
 => nil 
> Project.find(11).category
Project Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
 => nil
```

So clearly something isn't working. My migrations:

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :filename
      t.string :location
      t.integer :id
      t.references :category
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.integer :id
      t.string :name, :default => "Design"
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

---

And models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :id, :category_id
  has_many :projects 
    def to_hash
    {
      :id => self.id,
      :name => self.name
    }
  end
end
```

---

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :project_id, :filename, :location, :uploaded_file
  belongs_to :category
  def to_hash
    {
      :id => self.id,
      :filename => self.filename,
      :location => self.location
    }
  end
end
```

Where am I going wrong? Thank you in advance for reading through all this!

Answer (score 3):

You never saved the record.

```
project = Project.find(11)
project.category = Category.find(1)
project.save!
```

Comment: Bonus question: I can call "project.category.name" in the rails console and correctly get the name "Food," but in my Projects view I get an error when I try to reference project.category.name, although I can see other attributes like project.filename. Is this a routing error...?

Comment: That should probably be a new question. It would also be a lot clearer if you posted the error instead of just indicating that you got one.